# Can't select anything or see selection in the viewport

Tags: mesh, objects, select

I can't select anything in the 3D viewport, and I don't see the gizmos axis or selected objects.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Show Gizmo* and *Show Overlays* have been disabled in your viewport. If you enable them it should work properly.

[image: Show Gizmo and Overlays]

When the *Show Overlays* is disabled you don't see the outline of your selection and with *Show Gizmo* disabled the move gizmo isn't shown. The selection is still registered though and using <kbd>G</kbd> to move the object would still work.